# Spring Batch, get stepExecution in writer?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm trying to get the readCount from `StepExecution` so I can write it to my database in a `writer()`.

Is there a way to get `StepExecution` in the write (`JdbcBatchItemWriter`) part of a `Step` so I can call `getReadCount()` on it?

Comment: can you show your batch configuration

Answer (score 3):

You can annotate your method with `@AfterStep` or `@AfterWrite` annotations.
for example

```
@AfterStep
public void afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
   //do your thing
}
```

But then you need either extend `JdbcBatchItemWriter` or wrap it. It's up to you how you want to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

you class which will give will be as:
public class CustomStepListener implements StepExecutionListener {

```
@Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    System.out.println("StepExecutionListener - beforeStep");
}

@Override
public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    stepExecution.getReadCount();
    return null;
}
```

}

and configure this class where reader and writer are configured

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a work-around.

I put an incrementor in my RowMapper that wrote the rowCount to the DTO being initialised in it, that is incremented every time rowMapper is called (equal to the number of rows being passed to it).

This meant, as my control table writer would use the latest instantiated DTO, it would have the correct row count that i could write to my table.